# Blocking a user from filling out a form

Tags: kentico

we have had a user that submits our "contact us" form nearly every day with spam. This has been happening for months - is there a way to block this user/IP from filling out the form?

We have located the user & their information but haven't found any type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to implement recaptcha on your forms. Depending what version you're using it can be simple or a bit more work.  You could also do IP blocking on your firewall but it becomes troublesome if you don't keep up with it.

Comment: We do use a reCAPTCHA, and it doesn't seem to help. Since the form has been active, this user has submitted it over 200 times. :( Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In v2 reCaptcha you can set the "Security Preference".  I suggest moving it from the middle to "Most Secure".  This will help with those "bots" claiming to be people.

Comment: @BrendenKehren - well, we have the same on DevNet - those are not bots but real  people paid for submitting spam :( the only way is to block IP but as you said, they will change it frequently too.